# TypeScript: how to determine default value for generic type

Tags: generics, types, default

I was wondering if someone can help me with the following. I implemented a TypeScript static extension for creating an instance of a multidimensional array with an arbitrary number of dimensions (see code below), which I can use as follows:

```
var mat = Array.create<number>([2, 3]);
mat[1][2] = 42; // the other 5 entries are undefined
```

Sofar the extension works fine. What I would like to achieve in addition, is that all entries get a default value that is depending on the actual value of the generic type parameter. For **number** it would be 0, for **String** it would be "" and for **boolean** it would be false (like default(T) in C#, for which unfortunately there is no TypeScript equivalent). I made various attempts to achieve this, and finally ended up with the solution as shown in the code. But unfortunately this does not work: all entries remain undefined. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance -- *John Pool / Amsterdam / Netherlands*

```
interface ArrayConstructor
{
  create: <T>(dimensions: number[]) => Array<T>
}

Array.create = function <T>(dimensions: number[])
{
  let k = dimensions[0];

  if (dimensions.length == 1)
  {
    // the code fragment below does not work as I hoped & expected
    let t: T;
    var z: any;

    if (typeof t == "string")
      z = "";
    else if (typeof t == "number")
      z = 0;
    else if (typeof t == "boolean")
      z = false;
    // -----------------------------------------------------

    return (Array<T> (k)).fill (z);
  }

  let result = Array (k);

  for (var i = 0; i < k; i++)
    result [i] = Array.create (dimensions.slice (1)); // create the sub-arrays

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Generics are a compile time feature of typescript, while `typeof` is a runtime feature of javascript. The reason that your code doesn't work is because the generic disappears after compilation.

This is what your code looks like after compilation:

```
Array.create = function (dimensions) {
    var k = dimensions[0];
    if (dimensions.length == 1) {
        // the code fragment below does not work as I hoped & expected
        var t = void 0;
        var z;
        if (typeof t == "string")
            z = "";
        else if (typeof t == "number")
            z = 0;
        else if (typeof t == "boolean")
            z = false;
        // -----------------------------------------------------
        return (Array(k)).fill(z);
    }
    var result = Array(k);
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++)
        result[i] = Array.create(dimensions.slice(1)); // create the sub-arrays
    return result;
};
```

Note that t becomes `void 0` to allow the code to still run.

It may not be as pretty, but instead of using a generic you may just want to have the a second parameter with a "type" enum

```
enum Type {
  number,
  string,
  boolean
}

interface ArrayConstructor
{
  create: (dimensions: number[], type: Type) => Array<T>
}
```

Then you can easily check for what you would like the default values to be.

Alternatively you can do your type checking to find defaults, on the insertion of values into the array through another extension method

Comment: Hi Rehan, thanks for your answer. Another option is that I simply supply the default value itself as the second parameter. While testing this I, hit upon another problem. When I try to declare a matrix of type string:

   var mat = Array.create<string>([2, 3], "");
   mat[1][2] = "42";

I get a compiler message “Index signature in type ‘string’ only permits reading. I have to sort out what this means.

Comment: Hi Rehan, thanks for your answer. Another option is that I simply supply the default value itself as the second parameter. While testing this I, hit upon another problem. When I try to declare a matrix of type string:  

   `var mat = Array.create<string>([2, 3], "");`  
   `mat[1][2] = "42";`  

I get a compiler message _Index signature in type ‘string’ only permits reading_. I have to sort out what this means.